# How to parse and address a json matrix array in Excel-VBA?

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba

I need to parse JSON text to a JSON object in Excel-VBA. The JSON text includes a matrix/array.  Then I need to address it (set a VBA variable to the value).

My code had been working parsing a nested/keyed JSON text with "JsonConverter.parseJSON" method.  But I do not know how to address new array object (or technically if the "parse" is working correctly.

```
Dim jsonResults As String
Dim jsonObj As Dictionary
Set travelDist As Number

Set jsonResults = '{"distances":[[0,97641],[97415,0]],"times":[[0,4189],[4183,0]],"weights":[[0.0,5653.726],[5644.176,0.0]],"info":{"copyrights":["GraphHopper","OpenStreetMap contributors"]}}'

Set jsonObj = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonResults) \This worked with the old JSON text keyed value structure.

travelDist = VBA.Val(jsonObj.Item("distances")(1)) \This DOESN'T work. It worked with Keyed Object Values.  The goal is to set travelDist to in this example, 97641.
```

The current code seems to have a type mismatch.

The goal is to set a VBA variable to 97641. Please let me know how to include required files/definitions etc. if the solution is including additional types or methods.

Comment: Distances is an array (and so converts to a collection) containing two arrays (each in turn converted to collections stored in the first collection).  So `distances(1)(1)` = 0, `distances(1)(2)` = 97641

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to declare `jsonObj` as a dictionary and unless `Number` is a well defined `user-defined` type of some sort, I don't think declaring travelDist as `Number` will work. Use `Double` instead. And always use `Option Explicit` on the very top.

Also the double quotes in the `JSON` string need to be escaped somehow. You can either double them:

```
jsonResults = "{""distances"":[[0,97641],[97415,0]],""times"":[[0,4189],[4183,0]],""weights"":[[0.0,5653.726],[5644.176,0.0]],""info"":{""copyrights"":[""GraphHopper"",""OpenStreetMap contributors""]}}"
```

or replace them with single quotes:

```
jsonResults = "{'distances':[[0,97641],[97415,0]],'times':[[0,4189],[4183,0]],'weights':[[0.0,5653.726],[5644.176,0.0]],'info':{'copyrights':['GraphHopper','OpenStreetMap contributors']}}"
```

or you can just store the string in a cell in one of your worksheets and load it from there:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet")
Set jsonObj = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sht.Range("A1"))
```

Visualizing the `JSON` structure might help you understand it better:

[image]

So basically what you need to do is access the `2nd item`, of the `1st item`, of the `distances` array/collection, keeping in mind that the `1st item` of the `distances` array is also an array/collection itself.

The way to do this would be the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim jsonObj As Object
Dim jsonResults As String
Dim travelDist As Double

jsonResults = "{""distances"":[[0,97641],[97415,0]],""times"":[[0,4189],[4183,0]],""weights"":[[0.0,5653.726],[5644.176,0.0]],""info"":{""copyrights"":[""GraphHopper"",""OpenStreetMap contributors""]}}"
Set jsonObj = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonResults)

travelDist = jsonObj("distances")(1)(2)
Debug.Print travelDist 'the result is printed in the immediate window
End Sub
```

Finally, I assume that since you've used this before, you know you need to add [this JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to your project, as well as a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (VBE>Tools>References>...)